# Re-generating Postman request from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm having an issue creating a POST request from C# to generate a token. There's nothing wrong with the service because I can consume it using Postman.

Can someone help my out.

Following my coding. Every time I get a 403 error.

```
public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials")
            };

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, login_url);
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);


            var client = new HttpClient();

            var authenticationBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("----------username-------- : ----------pwd----------");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authenticationBytes));
            //request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authenticationBytes));

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            var jwtResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // contains access token

            JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jwtResponse);

            accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("access_token");
            Debug.WriteLine(jwtResponse);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        return accessToken;

    }
```

Following are the screenshots of Postman.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to watch the requests from Postman and your C# app. Compare them and see what Postman is doing that your app is not. This will tell you the problem.

Comment: Perhaps the spaces between username:password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use generating code from postman using RestSharp Library for .Net as you can see  by clicking on code button below in the picture .
best regards

[image]

Comment: Your "answer" is unhelpful because the question says nothing about RestSharp.

Comment: I did try that, but it also failed, giving the same error.

Comment: @Sayah "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." is the error I'm getting.

Comment: It did the trick. Found an additional header line in my code. Had to add the following line to get it right. client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;